# How to show a div behind navigation on rollover

Tags: css, menu, navigation, jquery-animate, rollover

I'm still trying to get the hang of this web coding thing. Lord knows there is no knowing it all. SO, I'm reaching out in hopes of some help.

I have a div containing a `<nav>`, and let's say this nav has a `<ul>` with `<li>`'s inside it....
How would I go about making a picture appear behind the navigation based on the li highlighted. 
Say I have a vertical menu:

Home | Gallery | Contacts

and I want the images to extent freely. Lets say Mario appears in behind contacts on rollover. I want his head to overlap Gallery, but he should be behind Contacts. I do intend for these images to be to the far left so as not to interfere to badly with navigation. Can I do this with JUST CSS or will I need jQuery.

Comment: You could use the css property `background-image` if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing what you are trying to do here. Could you provide a little bit more detail on what you want it to look like? Or a graphic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/rMCMt/ ?

You can use first-child and nth-child selectors: http://jsfiddle.net/Qq9Nm/

As menu items have different widths, you have to adjust the padding and the margin individually.

The CSS code, below:

```
li
{
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 2px grey;
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
li:first-child:hover,
li:nth-child(2):hover,
li:nth-child(3):hover,
li:nth-child(4):hover,
li:nth-child(5):hover
{
    background-size: 200px 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 180px;
    margin-bottom: -170px;
}
li:first-child:hover
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/RqQtl');
    padding-right: 145px;
    margin-right: -135px;
}
li:nth-child(2):hover
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/TWI0t');
    padding-right: 130px;
    margin-right: -120px;
}
li:nth-child(3):hover
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/xRPiq');
    padding-right: 115px;
    margin-right: -105px;
}
li:nth-child(4):hover
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/u3Akz');
    padding-right: 140px;
    margin-right: -130px;
}
li:nth-child(5):hover
{
    background-image: url('http://goo.gl/Em9Ij');
    padding-right: 140px;
    margin-right: -130px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li> HOME </li>
      <li> GALLERY </li>
      <li> CONTACTS </li>
      <li> EXTRA1 </li>
      <li> EXTRA2 </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: YES IT IS! Thanks. Also, is there a way to make each have a hover image? I tried adding one for BBBBB, but couldn't make it function.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I needed. The "nth" is the piece I didn't know. This just solved my coding issue. Thank you so much.